# How do I reset this wp_list_categories query?

Tags: wp-query, template-tags, categories

How do I reset a query that generates a list of categories with wp_list_categories?

The query below builds a two column list of categories that is then displayed with the second code chunk.

I'm using two of these queries (with different category include strings) in a jQuery tab to display different lists of categories.

Problem is, the first query needs to be reset, because the second tab shows both lists of categories rather than categories from just the second query.

I've tried `<?php wp_reset_query();?>` but that only works for the WP loop. Anyone have any ideas?

```
    <?php
    $cats = explode
    ("<br />",wp_list_categories('title_li=&echo=0&depth=1&style=none&include=12,13,14,15,16'));
    $cat_n = count($cats) - 1;
    for ($i=0;$i<$cat_n;$i++):
    if ($i<$cat_n/2):
    $cat_left = $cat_left.'<li>'.$cats[$i].'</li>';
    elseif ($i>=$cat_n/2):
    $cat_right = $cat_right.'<li>'.$cats[$i].'</li>';
    endif; endfor; ?>

    <ul class="leftcatcolumn">
    <?php echo $cat_left;?>
    </ul>
    <ul class="rightcatcolumn">
    <?php echo $cat_right;?>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`wp_list_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) is a simple function that returns (or echos, depending on parameter) a list of links to category archives. It needs not to be reset.

When you create a new instance of the [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class you need to reset postdata, because [Template Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/) otherwise use that query and not the main query.

You've said:

> I'm using two of these queries (with different category include strings)...

I am assuming, the "category include strings" are the only difference in the two queries?!

In the second time you're using this snippet, the variables `$cat_left` and `$cat_right`are the actual culprits. They do not get overwritten, the new values are added to the end of the array.

Rename them to `$cat_left_2` and `$cat_right_2` the second time around or set them to [`NULL`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php) inbetween:

```
// first list here
$cat_left = NULL;
$cat_right = NULL;
// second list here
```

Comment: You're right; I was looking at the wrong aspects of the query. I changed the second set of cat calls to `$cat_left_1` and 2 and that worked. Thanks!